# A child is breastfed or breastfeeding?

Tags: verbs

I'm having trouble deciding whether you say:

- A child is breastfed until ...
- A child is breastfeeding until..

I have heard a native speaker used to second option, but to me that sound as if the child has a child of her own, who she is breastfeeding.

Also, consider this case:

- She was breastfeeding at that age
- She was being breastfed at that age

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*breastfed* past tense
*breastfeeding* present tense

> A child is breastfed until...  he is weaned.

Take away the "breast"

> A child is fed until full.

or..

> A child is breastfeeding until... he is full.?
>   A child is feeding until full. *This doesn't sound right*
>   A child is being breastfed until he is full. *formal*

which is akin to your:

> She was being breastfed at that age.    *formal*

Isn't the the best usage of *breastfeeding*.

*The mother is breastfeeding the baby in the next room. *

The following are correct:

> She was breastfeeding at that age.
>   She was being breastfed at that age.    *formal*

So is:

> *She was breastfed at that age.*  *informal*

**Edit**

I should add that breastfeeding is something the mother does to the child.

> The mother is breastfeeding the child.
>   subject=mother verb=breastfeeding object=child
>
> The child is eating.
>   subject=child verb=eating

**Edit 2**

It can be said;

> The child is breastfeeding. *where the child is the subject and is "having a feed"*

I know it is not the best use of the grammar, it is the fuzzy delineation between the action of the child feeding (as in eating) and the mother feeding (as in giving food).   It's akin to animals feeding.. animals have feed (noun), animals feed, and the farmer feeds them.
This really depends on the context of the conversation. As mothers (in particular) will refer to the child as feeding or breastfeeding, as they are proud/pleased of the child taking the bottle or  taking the breast.

> [verb (used without object)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fed)
>   11. (especially of animals) to take food; eat: cows feeding in a meadow; to feed well.
>   12. to be nourished or gratified; subsist: to feed on grass; to feed on thoughts of revenge.

Comment: Yes, so you can say 'I was breastfeeding until I was 4'?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: First off, ‘breastfed’ and ‘breastfeeding’ are not past and present—they are the passive and active participles of the verb. ‘Breastfed’ is used to form all tenses of the passive voice, and ‘breastfeeding’ is used to form all tenses of the continuous aspect. Secondly, this answer is quite messy; it took me a while to even figure out whether it was a positive or negative answer to the main question. **Edit 2** has made that clearer, at least.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are right: the second option, i.e.,

> A child is breastfeeding until..

means, in a correct usage, that the child has another child whom is breastfeeding.

*To be breastfed*, as well as *to be fed* implies a passive usage of the verb, which, as you can read in

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/breastfeed?s=t&ld=1148

means *to nurse*, *to feed via the breast*, so it's an action that goes from the mother to the child.

So, in the second of your couples of sentences,

> She was breastfeeding at that age

means that she, at that age, had a child and was breastfeeding him/her.

So I think that if you hear *breastfeed* used to mean that the child is receiving breastfeeding, then this is incorrect and must be an abuse of language that transfers the action from the subject to the object.

Comment: @Yve What do you mean: can the form "the child is breastfeeding from the mom" be correct?

Comment: This would be completely fine if it were "the child is breasteating" (which doesn't exist), I think. It's a simple switching in the language, no problems to the understanding but it's incorrect.

Comment: Many, though not all, dictionaries have ‘breast-feed’ as both a transitive and an intransitive verb. Intransitive uses are quite common, and saying they are wrong is not really very accurate. It is more accurate to say that the transitive uses outnumber the intransitive uses. ‘Breast-feed’ is an extension of the verb ‘feed’, which can also be both transitive and intransitive: the cattle feed, but the cowboy feeds the cattle. Similarly, a mother suckles her baby, but the baby suckles.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I've never encountered such intransitive usages for these verbs. But I'm not a native speaker. Do you have any online refs. for these vocabularies you mention?

Comment: @martina, if by “these verbs” you also mean ‘suckle’ and ‘feed’, then there should be plenty of references, because they are both very commonly used intransitively (often with the preposition ‘on’). I don’t have any references at hand for intransitive uses of ‘breast-feed’, but I have heard it used by native speakers many times. For example, if a baby has been sick and has refused food for a while, but is now on the mend, its mother might say, “She’s a bit better now. At least she’s breast-feeding again”.